# Possible to sort by letter grades?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

I have a table that I'd like to sort by letter grade. The issue is that it sorts letters before letters with symbols. For example, it sorts: A, A+, A-, B, B+, B-, etc., but I would like it to sort A+, A, A-, B+, B, B-, etc. Is there a way to set do this?

Comment: "Is there a way to set do this?" – You do it by writing a program which does that. If you have a problem with your program, carefully read the documentation of all the methods, classes, modules, and libraries you are using, write tests for your programs, trace the execution with pen and paper, single-step it in a debugger, then sleep on it, start again from the beginning, sleep on it again, and *then and only then* narrow your problem down to a concise, focused, simple, short [mre] and ask a specific, focused, narrow question on [so].

Comment: You could convert the letter grade to a numerical value from F = 0 to A+ = 12 for storage. This makes it trivial to sort by grade.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As idea you can check last letter of grade and depending on its value add some number to grade

You can add scope to your model

```
scope :order_by_grade, -> do
  sql = <<~SQL
    CASE RIGHT(grade, 1)
    WHEN '-' THEN grade || 3
    WHEN '+' THEN grade || 1
    ELSE grade || 2
    END
  SQL

  order(sql)
end
```

And then apply to your model `Work.order_by_grade`

As another idea you can define some constant in the model with all variants and use index

And may be better sort from the worst to the best as `ASC` and from the best to the worst as `DESC` -- it's your choice

```
GRADES = %w[A+ A A- B+ ...]

scope :order_by_grade, -> do
  sql = 'CASE grade '

  GRADES.reverse_each.with_index do |grade, index|
    sql << sanitize_sql_array(['WHEN ? THEN ?', grade, index])
  end

  sql << ' END'

  order(sql)
end
```

And then apply to your model `Work.order_by_grade` or even `Work.order_by_grade.reverse_order`

Answer (score 1):

You may write the following.

```
arr = ["A", "B-", "B+", "A-", "B", "A+"]
```

```
order = { '+' => 0, nil => 1, '-' => 2 }
```

```
arr.sort_by { |s| [s[0], order[s[1]]] }
  #=> ["A+", "A", "A-", "B+", "B", "B-"]
```

Two arrays are compared for ordering with the method [Array#<=>](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-3C-3D-3E). See especially the third paragraph at the link.

Suppose

```
s1 = 'A'
s2 = 'A+'
```

are being compared. For `s1` we compute the array

```
[s[0], order[s[1]]]
  #=> ['A', order[nil]]
  #=> ['A', 1]
```

For `s2`

```
[s[0], order[s[1]]]
  #=> ['A', order['+']]
  #=> ['A', 0]
```

As

```
['A', 0] <=> ['A', 1]
  #=> -1
```

`'A+'` is ordered before `'A'`.